# Chaining functions in a D3.js plugin

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a written a plugin for D3.js called [`d3-marcon`](https://github.com/HarryStevens/d3-marcon) that implements [Mike Bostock's margin conventions](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563). For example, rather than having to write:

```
var margin = {top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10},
    width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

You can write:

```
var setup = d3.marcon({top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10, width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight}),
    margin = setup.margin,
    width = setup.width,
    height = setup.height,
    svg = setup.svg;
```

As you can see, it works by passing an options object to the `marcon()` function. If you specify no options, it defaults to `0` for all margins, `900` for the width, `600` for the height, and appends the svg element to the `"body"`. So you can get up and running very quickly with just one line of code, `var setup = d3.marcon()`, and then pass options later when you want to change your viz.

This is useful, but it still doesn't feel like a real D3 function. Real D3 functions allow for chaining functions together, rather than passing options objects. So instead of `d3.marcon({element: ".viz"})`, D3 code looks like `d3.marcon().element(".viz")`.

D3 code also lets you pass additional functions to the chained functions (e.g. `d3.method().chainedFunction(function(d) { return d.value; })`), so you can update the attributes of an object based on data.

Obviously, my plugin does none of these things. I've spent a few hours looking at existing D3 modules to try to figure out how they work, but I'm not getting anywhere. Can anyone suggest how to get my code to work like a proper D3 module? Or, failing that, a good tutorial to read?

I linked to the repository above, but [here it is again](https://github.com/HarryStevens/d3-marcon). And [here is a block](https://bl.ocks.org/HarryStevens/de1069536e00256d7aa82299fac0f3d5) showing how it works.

Comment: Also have a look at the [d3-container](https://github.com/binaworks/d3-container) plugin which follows the approach proposed by Mark. The difference to your own plugin is, that it will append to an existing SVG element instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my suggestion, based on Nick Zhu's approach in his book *Data Visualization with D3 4.x*.

Basically, we create a function with an object...

```
function marcon() {
    var instance = {};
}
```

... and set each method individually:

```
instance.top = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return top;
    top = d;
    return instance;
};
```

At the end, you call the render part with `render()`:

```
marcon().top(10)
    .left(10)
    //etc...
    .render();
```

The nice thing about this approach is that, as you requested, it allows chaining. For instance, you can create your SVG like this:

```
var mySvg = marcon();

mySvg.top(20)
    .left(10)
    .right(10)
    .bottom(10)
    .height(200)
    .width(200)
    .element("body")
    .render();
```

Here is a demo:

```js
function marcon() {
  var instance = {};
  var top = 10,
    bottom = 0,
    left = 0,
    right = 0,
    width = 900,
    height = 600,
    element = "body",
    innerWidth, innerHeight, svg;

  instance.top = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return top;
    top = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.left = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return left;
    left = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.right = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return right;
    right = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.bottom = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return bottom;
    bottom = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.width = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.height = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.element = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return element;
    element = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.innerWidth = function() {
    return innerWidth;
  };

  instance.innerHeight = function() {
    return innerHeight;
  };

  instance.svg = function() {
    return svg;
  };

  instance.render = function() {
    innerWidth = width - left - right;
    innerHeight = height - top - bottom;
    svg = d3.select(element)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", innerWidth + left + right)
      .attr("height", innerHeight + top + bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + left + ", " + top + ")");
  }

  return instance;
}

var mySvg = marcon();
mySvg.top(20)
  .left(10)
  .right(10)
  .bottom(20)
  .height(200)
  .width(200)
  .element(".testDiv")
  .render();

var rect = mySvg.svg()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", mySvg.innerWidth())
  .attr("height", mySvg.innerHeight())
  .style("fill", "teal")
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: tan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="testDiv"></div>
```

Also, it allows defaults. If you don't set a setter, it defaults to the specified values. Here, if we don't set the width, it defaults to 900:

```js
function marcon() {
  var instance = {};
  var top = 10,
    bottom = 0,
    left = 0,
    right = 0,
    width = 900,
    height = 600,
    element = "body",
    innerWidth, innerHeight, svg;

  instance.top = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return top;
    top = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.left = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return left;
    left = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.right = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return right;
    right = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.bottom = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return bottom;
    bottom = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.width = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.height = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.element = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return element;
    element = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.innerWidth = function() {
    return innerWidth;
  };

  instance.innerHeight = function() {
    return innerHeight;
  };

  instance.svg = function() {
    return svg;
  };

  instance.render = function() {
    innerWidth = width - left - right;
    innerHeight = height - top - bottom;
    svg = d3.select(element)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", innerWidth + left + right)
      .attr("height", innerHeight + top + bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + left + ", " + top + ")");
  }

  return instance;
}

var mySvg = marcon();
mySvg.top(20)
  .left(10)
  .right(10)
  .bottom(20)
  .height(200)
  .element("body")
  .render();

var rect = mySvg.svg()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", mySvg.innerWidth())
  .attr("height", mySvg.innerHeight())
  .style("fill", "teal")
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: tan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="testDiv"></div>
```

Finally, you can use getters, like:

```
marcon().top();
```

Which gives you the value. Here is a demo, have a look at the console:

```js
function marcon() {
  var instance = {};
  var top = 10,
    bottom = 0,
    left = 0,
    right = 0,
    width = 900,
    height = 600,
    element = "body",
    innerWidth, innerHeight, svg;

  instance.top = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return top;
    top = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.left = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return left;
    left = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.right = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return right;
    right = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.bottom = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return bottom;
    bottom = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.width = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.height = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.element = function(d) {
    if (!arguments.length) return element;
    element = d;
    return instance;
  };

  instance.innerWidth = function() {
    return innerWidth;
  };

  instance.innerHeight = function() {
    return innerHeight;
  };

  instance.svg = function() {
    return svg;
  };

  instance.render = function() {
    innerWidth = width - left - right;
    innerHeight = height - top - bottom;
    svg = d3.select(element)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", innerWidth + left + right)
      .attr("height", innerHeight + top + bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + left + ", " + top + ")");
  }

  return instance;
}

var mySvg = marcon();
mySvg.top(20)
  .left(10)
  .right(10)
  .bottom(20)
  .height(200)
  .width(200)
  .element("body")
  .render();

var rect = mySvg.svg()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", mySvg.innerWidth())
  .attr("height", mySvg.innerHeight())
  .style("fill", "teal");
  
console.log("The height is " + mySvg.height())
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: tan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="testDiv"></div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you very much. You basically wrote my plugin for me. Two questions: (1) You cannot access `innerWidth()`, `innerHeight()` or `svg()` without first calling `render()`. Why is that? (2) You have included an argument, `d`, in each of those above three functions. Why?

Comment: @HarryStevens 1) `innerWidth`, `innerHeight` and `svg` are defined inside `render()`. The same thing happens in the answer you accepted: you cannot get `w`, `h` or `svg`. 2) Those parameters are not needed, I was copy/pasting the other methods and I just forgot to remove them... I just edited the answer.

Comment: I see, you're right. I wish I could accept two answers. But I see now that being able to return `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` is an advantage. The `render()` convention isn't a common D3 thing, but it seems fine.

Comment: In fact, I like that you have to explicitly call `render`. I just didn't like that you had to call `render` before you could get those other variables, so I changed that. I'll post a link when I publish the code. Thanks again!

Comment: Updated. https://github.com/HarryStevens/d3-marcon. Here's the block: https://bl.ocks.org/HarryStevens/de1069536e00256d7aa82299fac0f3d5

Comment: @HarryStevens Nice! But here is an advice: if I were you I wouldn't publish it right now, I'd work on it a bit more. You see, my answer as well as Mark's answer are just general ideas, they are very crude... I wrote that in 5 minutes. Thus, there is a lot of room for improvement here. Also, you have some problems right now in your documentation: for instance, `viz.svg()` does not return the SVG, It returns the `<g>` element instead, and `marcon()` doesn't accept any argument.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple different ways to do what you are after.  First, you should read this excellent [tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) on re-usability with `d3`.  Taking those ideas with your code would look something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function marcon() {
      
      var top = 0,
       bottom = 0,
       left = 0,
       right = 0,
       width = 900,
       height = 600,
       svg;

      function self(selection) {
        
      var w = width - left - right,
          h = height - top - bottom;
      
      svg = selection.append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + left + right)
       .attr("height", height + top + bottom)
       .append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + left + ", " + top + ")");
     }

      self.top = function(value) {
        if (!arguments.length) return top;
        top = value;
        return self;
      };

      self.bottom = function(value) {
        if (!arguments.length) return bottom;
        bottom = value;
        return self;
      };
      
      self.left = function(value) {
        if (!arguments.length) return left;
        left = value;
        return self;
      };
      
      self.right = function(value) {
        if (!arguments.length) return right;
        right = value;
        return self;
      };
      
      self.width = function(value) {
        if (!arguments.length) return width;
        width = value;
        return self;
      };
      
      self.height = function(value) {
        if (!arguments.length) return height;
        height = value;
        return self;
      };
      
      self.svg = function(value){
        if (!arguments.length) return svg;
        svg = value;
        return self;
      }


      return self;
    }
    
    var m = marcon()
      .width(100)
      .height(100)
      .top(50)
      .left(50);
    
    d3.select('body')
      .call(m);
      
    m.svg()
      .append("text")
      .text("Hi Mom!");
    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It works perfectly. I can't decide if I prefer the requirement that you `call()` it on a selection. On the one hand, it doesn't allow you to default to appending to the `body`, which is how I would often use it (e.g. for making blocks). On the other hand, maybe it's better if you explicitly have to call it on an element. I think it would also allow you to call the same "instance" of `marcom()` on multiple elements. Is that the logic behind the `call()` function?

Comment: @hazards, the `.call` is just syntactic sugar that's passing the current selection into the instance of marcom.  It's the same as doing `var m = marcom(); var s = d3.select('body'); m(s);`  Essentially, it's a `d3` trick to allow yet more method chaining when operating on a selection.